# how to generate random dates list within a given range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to crate a list of 60 random dates between 01/01/1949 to 01/01/2004.

Steps I took:

1. formatted the column as format -> number -> date -> mm/dd/yyyy.

2.used this formula in cell: `=RANDBETWEEN(1/1949,1/1/2004)` and got #NUM! error:

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you want to freeze the randomly generated dates?

Comment: as a matter of fact yes.

Comment: can those dates repeat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201364/5632629

Comment: a few may but not systematically as it needs to simulate birth dates. so i guess among 60 individuals a few may share birth date

Answer (score 1):

Another option generating array:

```
=ArrayFormula(DATE(1949,1,1)+RANDARRAY(60,1)*DATEDIF(DATE(1949,1,1),DATE(2004,1,1),"D"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the values passed to RANDBETWEEN should be integers.

You can use this expression to generate the required random dates:

> =date(1949,1,1)+randbetween(0,date(2004,1,1)-date(1949,1,1))

Answer (score 0):

There are 20088 days between your date range:

`=datedif(datevalue("1/1/1949"),datevalue("1/1/2004"),"D")`

or  `=datevalue("1/1/2004")-datevalue("1/1/1949")`

Therefore try this to get a sequential list of random dates:

```
=arrayformula(query(datevalue("1/1/1949")+int(RANDARRAY(60,1)*20088),"order by Col1",0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK - FYI,
It tried out this syntax and it works like a charm:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1949, 1, 1),(DATE(2004,1,1)))
```

Many thanks for all those who suggested their answers above