# Google Sheets - Randomize and freeze queried columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a dynamic 'worksheet' in Google Sheets to help myself study Chinese.

This is something I'm kind of figuring out as I go, but I'm currently trying to create a template for the basic 'worksheet' that will draw vocabulary from other pages in my document.

Here's a copy of my current version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U1hclOSo-SM2JuxJB6LXPB4J0UzXt6xJ1B_54ehkALs/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet1 is where I'm currently struggling. The idea behind Column A was that I could create 'switches' to keep the page from updating (Freeze) while I'm actually using the worksheet for studying. Once I've finished and checked my work, I could switch back to (Update) so that the Query will re-run and update to include any new words, etc.

Thus, E2 `=if(A2="Update",1,0)` is the condition I'm trying to check. 1 in this case would be letting the page update. 0 would be the only other value (Freeze), which would ideally stop the sheet from updating.

Another problem I've run into is that I wanted to use the 'Randomize Range' feature from the right-click menu on the output of my Query, but that doesn't seem to work. I wanted to be able to shuffle the terms so that I am not accidentally memorizing the order rather than the actual information I'm trying to learn.

I don't know which is more efficient: Having the Query grab the definition along with the word and add those to a hidden column, or have a column that matches the word to its definition outside of the Query.

If I could add in another layer of complexity, it would be neat if I could have my worksheet randomly choose between column A and column D (maybe E, too) on my Vocabulary Bank pages so that sometimes it would show me the English term and other times it would show me the Chinese one. (Currently, I'm planning to just have one worksheet for English to Chinese and a second for Chinese to English.)

In the end, I'd like for Sheet1 to work like this:

**Column A:** Switches

**Column B:** Terms, grabbed from `'Vocabulary Bank - [etc.]'!A3:A` [etc.] being all of the different banks. These are randomly reordered and 'frozen' until the Range switch is changed to 'Update'.

**Column C:** Hidden, containing the translations of the corresponding words. These update according to a switch.

**Column D:** This is where I enter my guesses at the translations. There is a switch to enable 'grading' where answers that don't match Column C are highlighted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: see: **https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201364/5632629**

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. Very cool workaround for making on-demand random numbers.

I'm having trouble correlating these random numbers with what I'm trying to do, though. For example, how do I equate these random numbers to A1:A (not blank) on my other sheets?

Comment: Have you considered using an Apps Script function to be triggered with a button and then update the Sheet 1 when you want?