# Automatic timestamp update upon edit

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns. When any column gets updated, I need it to update the timestamp on column 5 which is our timestamp column:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zOKwPL0LMtWpcbhji6XDi-8Sx3-WfxRXnboZ_Le0wZo/edit?usp=sharing

but I can't for the life figure out why it won't work.

Comment: i have played with a copy of the file, and even after fixing some things (correcting sheet name, making the apps script and spreadsheet same timezone) the script still will not function correctly due to the slicer. but after removing the slicer, several timestamp scripts i have will all work without issue. sorry i do not have a script that takes the slicer into account while also adding the timestamp onEdit.

Answer (score 0):

try this answer from [stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31894/google-spreadsheet-timestamp/31942#31942)

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

You can try adding a Google Apps Script to capture when a cell is edited and add a timestamp to a different cell

Answer (score 0):

The current script that you have will work (putting timestamp in column `I`) after a few minor edits AND removal of the Slicer

1. go into the Apps Script and correct the sheet name from:

```
  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && ss.getName()=='Sheet1') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (I)  And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
```

to:

```
  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && ss.getName()=='Sheet 1') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (I)  And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
```

2. while in the Apps Script editor, change the App Script's timezone by using the `Legacy editor` and clicking `File > Project properties > Time Zone` from the menu above the script editor.
3. Save the Apps Script, and return to the spreadsheet.
4. Change G-Sheets timezone (to match the timezone you selected in the Apps Script) by clicking `File > Spreadsheet settings`
5. Remove the Slicer
6. Test the script is working

I have tried several scripts that normally work (without Slicer), but the Slicer interferes with all of them so i can not offer you a script that works with the current Spreadsheet design while it uses the Slicer.

---

For a script that puts timestamp in column E when any edits are made in any other column, you can try this:

```
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const SHEETNAME = 'Sheet 1'; // SHEET to MONITOR
  const COLTSL = 'E'; // COLUMN LETTER to TIMESTAMP

function onEdit(e) {
  let r = sh.getActiveCell();
  // If Edit is done in any column other than the timestamp column,  And sheet name is Sheet 1 then:
  if (r.getColumn() !== COLTSL && sh.getName() == SHEETNAME) { 
  let celladdress = COLTSL + r.getRowIndex() 
    sh.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
}
```

However, this still has limitation that setValue will not function correctly (some rows work, others do not) while you have the Slicer enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure have your question got a solution. I had the same struggle as yours over the year, and I found a solution that works for my case nicely.

Some **background** for my case:

- I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheet to run and generate the
  timestamp
- I want to skip my first sheet without running to generate timestamp
  in it
- I want every edit, even if each value that I paste from Excel to
  generate timestamp
- I want the timestamp to be individual, each row have their own
  timestamp precise to every second
- I don't want a total refresh of the entire sheet timestamp when I am
  editing any other row
- I have a column that is a MUST FILL value to justify whether the
  timestamp needs to be generated for that particular row
- I want to specify my timestamp on a dedicated column only

```
function timestamp() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const totalSheet = ss.getSheets();

  for (let a=1; a<totalSheet.length; a++) {
    let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a];
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let values = range.getValues(); 

    function autoCount() {
      let rowCount;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rowCount = i
        if (values[i][0] === '') {
          break;
        }
      }
      return rowCount
    }

    rowNum = autoCount()

    for(let j=1; j<rowNum+1; j++){
      if (sheet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '') {
        sheet.getRange(j+1,7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. First, I made a `const totalSheet` with `getSheets()` and run it
   with a `for` loop. That is to identify the total number of sheets
   inside that spreadsheet. Take note, in here, I made `let a=1;`
   supposed all JavaScript the same, starts with `0`, value `1` is to
   **skip the first sheet** and run on the second sheet onwards
2. then, you will notice a function `let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a]`
   inside the loop. Take note, it is not supposed to use `const` if
   your value inside the **variable is constantly changing**, so use
   `let` instead will work fine.
3. then, you will see a `function autoCount()`. That is to make a `for`
   loop to count the number of rows that have values edited in it. The
   `if (values[i][0] === '')` is to navigate the script to search
   through the entire sheet that has value, looking at the row `i` and
   the column `0`. Here, the `0` is indicating the **first column** of the
   sheet, and the `i` is the row of the sheet. Yes, it works like a
   `json` object with `panda` feeling.
4. then, you found the number of rows that are edited by running the
   `autoCount()`. Give it a `rowNum` variable to contain the result.
5. then, pass that `rowNum` into a new `for` loop, and use `if (sheeet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '')` to determine which row
   has not been edited with timestamp. Take note, where the `7` here
   indicating the **7th column** of the sheet is the place that I want a
   timestamp.
6. inside the `for` loop, is to `setValue` with date in a specified
   format of `("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`. You are free to edit into any
   style you like
7. ohya, do remember to deploy to activate the trigger with event type
   as `On Change`. That is not limiting to edit, but for all kinds of
   changes **including paste**.

Here's a screenshot on how it would look like:

[image: First Column Value 7th Column Timestamp]

Lastly, please take note on some of my backgrounds before deciding to or not to have the solution to work for your case. Cheers, and happy coding~!

Answer (score 0):

no more scripts needed:

```
=LAMBDA(x, IF(JOIN(, A2:D2)="",,x))(IFERROR(A2:D2/0)+NOW())
```

[image]

more at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201717/5632629