# Processing of generating random names, grouping into 4. Then I'd like to compare the list to history. Any ideas?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am in the process of generating random names using =Rand(), grouping into 4 using =rank() and filtering. Using that group of 4 I create 2 teams of 2 which creates a random pairing doubles match. I then do this for several games and matches. My problem occurs due to keeping a track of who has played with each other before.

For example week 1 Player A & Player B and Player C & D. The following week Player A & Player D vs Player C & B this is an example using only 4 players but we have upto 20 members could potentially come and play. Also not everyone comes every week.

Any ideas of how I could ensure the players weren't partnered (exist in the list) with previous pairings but keeping it random. As I have generated it several times but it always has gaps of partners who have played before.

Happy to share my google sheet document - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIO4yvMixfPP6uI7RZeoQfB5XCWq6zQOQy1E0ICTmQE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks,
J

Comment: Maybe create a list of all possible pairings to start with. Then apply `RAND()` to the list of pairings. Then track which pairings have occurred. Pairings with an absent member get filtered out before match assignments.

Comment: Similar to @bugdrown 's suggestion,  but I'd say generate a list of all possible  pairs,  and from that generate a list of all possible matches.  Then shuffle that match list.  Then starting at the top of that list, each week play matches from list.  Each week skip any match where a player is absent.   Mark off each played match

Comment: due to the nature of RAND this wont be doable as you imagine it. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201717/5632629

Comment: Can anyone suggest an alternative way or an example of doing this?

Comment: @bugdrown the only problem with doing the way suggested is that not everyone turns up each week. Which is why I am using Rand to ensure the pairings are randomly generated.

Comment: @chrisneilsen the only problem with doing the way suggested is that not everyone turns up each week. Which is why I am using Rand to ensure the pairings are randomly generated.

Comment: @Jess Sheasby you could apply rand to the pairings that have shown up.

Comment: @jess I addressed that in my suggestion : "Each week skip any match where a player is absent."