# ArrayFormula For Google Script that Generates RAndom Number based on cell data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, random, array-formulas

I have the following code to generate a random number between 0 and the number in Cell D16. The information on the sheet is being updated via a form and I want to know if there is a way to do an ArrayFormula with this code so that I can generate the numbers going down a column without having to type the code for each and every row.

```
function economyNegative() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SubmittedPolicies');
    sheet.getRange('E16').setValue(Math.random() * sheet.getRange('D16').getValue());
}
```

Comment: What about duplicate random numbers?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want the random numbers stay put or get refreshed on every row whenever another form response is submitted?

Comment: @TheWizEd duplicates are fine but I don't want them to regenerate everytime the sheet is updated. That's why I thought a script would be the best option

Comment: @doubleunary Preferably to stay put whenever new data is added.

Comment: Try `PseudoRandomSequence()`. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(E16:E),1,D16,0)))
```

### Explanation

The `SEQUENCE` function is used with its fourth argument being 0 to generate an array of numbers that are all identical. This is fed into the `RANDBETWEEN` function (which is wrapped in `ARRAYFORMULA`) to generate an array of values between 0 and whichever number is returned by the `SEQUENCE`.

`ROWS(E16:E)` is used to make sure that the results do not overflow the spreadsheet—the sequence's length is capped by the number of rows available.

If you wish to have the formula only return a single value once and have it stay consistent regardless of how you edit the sheet, please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201364/how-to-stop-freeze-pause-volatile-rand-randbetween-randarray).

Functions used:

- [ROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en)
- [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en)
- [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you want that all those random numbers get refreshed whenever another form response is submitted, use `ifs()` and `randarray()` in an array formula in row 1 of a free column, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    row(D1:D) = 1, "Random", 
    isnumber(D1:D), D1:D * randarray(rows(D1:D)), 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

If you want the random numbers to stay put, use the [PseudoRandomSequence](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/97576768?msgid=97778056) custom function in an array formula in row 1 of a free column, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    row(D1:D) = 1, "Random", 
    isnumber(D1:D), D1:D * PseudoRandomSequence(42, 0, 10^6 - 1, rows(D1:D)) / 10^6, 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```