# Randbetween until a specific day?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to have the randbetween function only return a random number until a specific day, then stop changing. Is there a way to accomplish this in googlesheets?

```
=IF(today()<F1,randbetween(1,10),)
```

I tried something like this, but it would just go blank if it's false.

Comment: you would need to use AppScript for this.

Comment: I agree with @MattKing, since the best way to do this will be with Google Apps script, since `randbetween(min,max)` will always change when the page is refreshed or the file is open. Will you be interested in using Apps Script?

Comment: @MattKing indeed, or is it... :)

Comment: @player0, that formula and the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201364) was awesome! I learn something new thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure there is you just need to summon the animal overlord... and avoid using `TODAY()` directly in the formula

let F1 be your date
let F2 be `=TODAY()`

then use:

```
=IF(F2<F1, RANDBETWEEN(1, 10), 
 UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(LEN(
 WHATTHEFOXSAY()&WHATTHEFOXSAY())&" "&TRANSPOSE(LEN(WHATTHEFOXSAY()&WHATTHEFOXSAY()))), " "), 
 "select Col1+Col2 label Col1+Col2''")&"", "\d$")+1))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fOLxZ_mhhhLqCjP0tWR4-a-LrgeCVAdXayCVSEP2o8I/copy)

to learn more about alchemy follow the great white **[fox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201364/5632629)**

Comment: This seems to be working! Out of curiosity what is the false result rand between?

Comment: @plerpsandplerps not sure I understand your question ?