# How can I return todays date (today() ) in an if function in google sheet?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula

Used the function

```
=IF(A1="TRUE",TODAY(),"Date not verified")
```

Tried to get the date published in second column if the check box is TRUE or checked. But seems that my logic is not working

Comment: Note two things: 1) you tag Excel and ask for Google sheets. They're not the same. 2) TODAY() will update to a next day if the same sheet is opened the next day. Is that the intention?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(A1=TRUE, TODAY(), "Date not verified")
```

you may also want to check out the 2nd formula from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201717/5632629