# How to generate a random alphanumeric string with a formula in Excel (or Google Sheets or LibreOffice)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, random, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to generate a random 8 character alphanumeric string in Excel (or Google Sheets or Libreoffice, which both have the same challenge) using a formula. I'd like to get something like this:

```
6n1a3pax
```

I've tried various formulae including ones like this which generate the ASCII characters for individual random numbers between an upper and lower number:

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) &CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))& CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))
```

However, they're lengthy, you have to repeat the `RANDBETWEEN()` function multiple times inside a formula, and you can't choose both "alpha" and "numeric" in the same `RANDBETWEEN()`.

Is there any easy way to do this in Excel, Google Sheets or LibreOffice Calc? If a solution works in one and not in the others then great if you can mention which one(s).

(N.B. This is not a duplicate of questions about how to stop recalculation of randomisation functions in Excel)

Comment: Google Sheets, Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc each have different feature sets. Choose one of them and edit tags appropriately.

Comment: Are you allowed to use macros?

Comment: No macros allowed unfortunately. ;-)

Comment: @doubleunary thanks - Excel, Google Sheets and Libreoffice all have the same challenge, there's no easy way to solve for them either. I'll edit though to make that clear.

Comment: BTW someone marked this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201364/how-to-stop-freeze-pause-volatile-rand-randbetween-randarray and closed the question. It's not a duplicate of that question, which asks how to "fix" cells displaying random(ised) output. This asks how to generate an alphanumeric string easily in a spreadsheet.

Comment: the answer can be also found there...

Comment: @player0 - thanks. I see an answer which helps (e.g. "generate hex code 9 characters long"), but I didn't see it until now (and others won't, I believe) because the question is asking something different, namely how to stop reloading of volatile functions containing randomisation functions. I have a simple answer to my own question, but can't post it here because the question has been closed. If I post it as an answer to the other question it won't be relevant because it's not answering that question.

Comment: added alternative

Comment: Thanks @player0 - I like your answer too, so let's hope someone reopens the question. ;-)

Comment: I can reopen it for you to post the answer...

Comment: Thanks @player0 - I could only vote for it to be reopened

Comment: Of course I also tried this with chatGPT: "Generate 50 different 8-character hexadecimal strings." And it did. 

Comment: Google Sheets, Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc each have different feature sets and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

in GS try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, x)(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, HEX2DEC("FFFFFFFF")), 8))
```

if that's not enough and you need

- A-Z     `char 65-90`
- a-z     `char 97-122`
- 0-9     `char 48-58`

---

```
=JOIN(, BYROW(SEQUENCE(8), LAMBDA(x, IF(COINFLIP(), IF(COINFLIP(), 
 CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 90)), CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97, 122))), RANDBETWEEN(0, 9)))))
```

[image]

frozen:

```
=LAMBDA(x, x)(JOIN(, BYROW(SEQUENCE(8), LAMBDA(x, IF(COINFLIP(), IF(COINFLIP(), 
 CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 90)), CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97, 122))), RANDBETWEEN(0, 9))))))
```

---

### alternative (with better distribution):

```
=JOIN(, BYROW(SEQUENCE(8), LAMBDA(x, SINGLE(SORT(CHAR({
 SEQUENCE(10, 1, 48); 
 SEQUENCE(26, 1, 65); 
 SEQUENCE(26, 1, 97)}), 
 RANDARRAY(62, 1), )))))
```

[image]

or frozen:

```
=LAMBDA(x, x)(JOIN(, BYROW(SEQUENCE(8), LAMBDA(x, SINGLE(SORT(CHAR({
 SEQUENCE(10, 1, 48); 
 SEQUENCE(26, 1, 65); 
 SEQUENCE(26, 1, 97)}), 
 RANDARRAY(62, 1), ))))))
```

---

for more see: **[stackoverflow.com/questions/66201364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201364)**

Comment: What is the use of `COINFLIP()` ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it's a coin toss 50% one side 50% the other side

Comment: Ah ok, so its available for every `Google Sheet` user right, its a new function, just saw for the first time.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes its avail for all users and no, its not a new function. its a hidden (undocumented) function

Comment: Okay sounds good, its like the `DATEDIF()` in Excel. Great Share  Learnt something new.

Answer (score 4):

**LibreOffice Calc 7.x**:

A non-volatile option for LibreOffice Calc 7.x is the use of the [`RANDBETWEEN.NV()`](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/RANDBETWEEN.NV) function:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=CONCAT(IF({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",RANDBETWEEN.NV(1,62),1),))
```

***Note*** that using `ROW(1:8)` would still force recalculation when any value in rows 1-8 have been made (thus *volatile*):

```
=CONCAT(IF(ROW(1:8),MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",RANDBETWEEN.NV(1,62),1),))
```

---

**Excel ms365**:

Unfortunately there is, AFAIK, not a non-volatile Excel equivalent to this function. If volatility is not a problem, then try:

```
=CONCAT(MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",RANDARRAY(8,,1,62,1),1))
```

Comment: There are 62 characters in `A-Za-z0-9` rather than 64.

Comment: @doubleunary, that's it! Thanks for the razer sharp mind and eyes. Edited

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take, for Google Sheets:

```
=lambda(_, 
  _ 
)(
  lambda( 
    numWords, wordLength, charRegex, ascii,
    lambda( 
      alphabet, 
      map( 
        sequence(numWords), 
        lambda(_, 
          concatenate( 
            map( 
              sequence(wordLength), 
              lambda(_, 
                mid(alphabet, randbetween(1, len(alphabet)), 1) 
              ) 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    )(concatenate(filter(ascii, regexmatch(ascii, charRegex)))) 
  )(10, 8, "[0-9a-zA-Z]", arrayformula(char(sequence(127)))) 
)
```

The formula will generate `10` passwords of `8` characters each from an alphabet that includes lower and upper case letters, and digits.

To choose which characters to include in the alphabet, replace `[0-9a-zA-Z]` with another regex like `[0-9a-z!#$%&/]` or `[-!#$%&/\w]`. Note that you may need to \escape any regex special characters there.

The pattern avoids the non-uniform distribution issues that plague some of the solutions presented in this thread. The ones that use `coinflip()` or `isodd(rand()*N)` will give results that overrepresent smaller sub alphabets like `0-9`. The ones that use `sort()` will not repeat any chars in the result, which is not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this in Excel using a combination of the following functions:

`SEQUENCE()` `VSTACK()` `RANDARRAY()` `CHAR()` `INDEX()` `TEXTJOIN()`

Unfortunately this doesn't work in LibreOffice (at the moment) as it does not have the `SEQUENCE()` function. It does not work in Google Sheets as the `RANDARRAY()` function only takes 2 parameters and the `VSTACK()` function does not exist, although you can use braces and a semicolon, e.g. `{SEQUENCE(26,1,97,1);SEQUENCE(10,1,48,1)}`.

Here's the formula you need:

Upper-case e.g "413BK5S0": `=TEXTJOIN("",1,INDEX(CHAR(VSTACK(SEQUENCE(26,1,65,1),SEQUENCE(10,1,48,1))),RANDARRAY(8,1,1,36,TRUE)))`

Lower-case e.g. "b8etbno8": `=TEXTJOIN("",1,INDEX(CHAR(VSTACK(SEQUENCE(26,1,97,1),SEQUENCE(10,1,48,1))),RANDARRAY(8,1,1,36,TRUE)))`

The following explanation for each function:

- `SEQUENCE()` - a sequence of e.g. 26 numbers, in 1 column, starting at number 65, increasing by 1 each time (with the second incidence of the function being 10 numbers starting at 48)
- `VSTACK()` - combine the 2 `SEQUENCE()` formulae into 1 array (sequence) of numbers
- `CHAR()` - the ASCII character associated with a decimal ASCII number (where the decimal number is generated by the `SEQUENCE()` function) - see https://www.asciitable.com/
- `RANDARRAY()` - an array of 8 random numbers, 1 column wide, minimum number 1, maximum 36
- `INDEX()` - the value from each element within the sequence of characters, where each of 8 element numbers is provided by `RANDARRAY()`
- `TEXTJOIN()` - join the values in an array together into one cell, with no separator and ignoring empty values

Comment: VSTACK() is not a valid function in GS

Comment: Thanks @player0 - you're right there. You can do `{SEQUENCE(26,1,97,1),SEQUENCE(10,1,48,1)}` but then you run into problems with `RANDARRAY()` only taking 2 parameters instead of Excel's 5. I'll update the answer to be clear it's Excel only.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of something like this?

```
=CONCATENATE(BYROW(SEQUENCE(8),LAMBDA(e,IF(ISODD(ROUNDUP(RAND()*10)),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)),ROUNDDOWN(RAND()*10)))))
```

[image]

If you want to include lower case, you can do a similar logic:

```
=CONCATENATE(BYROW(SEQUENCE(8),LAMBDA(e,IF(ISODD(ROUNDUP(RAND()*10)),IF(ISODD(ROUNDUP(RAND()*10)),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))),ROUNDDOWN(RAND()*10)))))
```

The logic is the next one: what I'm doing is with `ISODD(ROUNDUP(RAND()*10)` generating a random number between 1 and 10 and checking if it's odd. If it is, it generates a letter or else it generates a number. With `CONCATENATE(BYROW(SEQUENCE(8)...` I'm doing this 8 times and concatenating them. What I just added was a second "random and odd" time when it's time to generate a letter so you can have upper and lower case

[image]

Comment: I was reading that previous post to which this one was referred. My ISODD(ROUNDUP(RAND()*10) is basically replaced with COINFLIP(). Good to know that alternative!