# Copy and Paste Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, input, range, output, copy-paste

[image]I have two goggle sheets on the same document. I need to transfer specific ranges from one sheet to another one,  on  specific ranges inside that sheet. I would like to add a time stamp once there new edit is done.There is going to be a button to use as a trigger so the data must be pasted on the next row available [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timestamp upon cell edit:

```
=LAMBDA(x; x)(IFERROR(B1/0)+NOW())
```

timestamp upon range edit:

```
=LAMBDA(x; x)(IFERROR(B1:B10/0)+NOW())
```

more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201717/5632629