# How do I create a list of non-repeating cells/numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to emulate Minesweeper in Google Sheets, and for this I want to create a second map adjacent to the first with all of the correct values already in it. To randomize bomb position, I need a list of random numbers or cells(cells would be preferable). However, I cannot figure out how to do this without ending up repeating numbers. The result would ideally be a vertical array of cell coordinates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=SORTN(FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(10,10,LAMBDA(row,col,ADDRESS(row,col)))),20,,RANDARRAY(100),)
```

In `=MAKEARRAY`, change the first `10` to adjust how many rows to randomly choose from, or the second `10` to adjust how many columns to choose from. The value in `=RANDARRAY` must be equal to the product of the number of rows and the number of columns. (e.g. in the above example, 10*10=100).

Change the `20` to adjust how many randomly chosen values to return.

### Explanation

`=MAKEARRAY` is used to generate an array of every possible row and column combination. It accepts a `=LAMBDA`, which in this case is just the `=ADDRESS` function. The first two arguments of `=MAKEARRAY` determine how large the array should be, which is why changing them adjusts how many rows/columns to randomly pick from.

Then, the result of `=MAKEARRAY` is squashed into a single column using the `=FLATTEN` formula.

Finally, the entire thing is sorted randomly using `=SORTN` combined with `=RANDARRAY`. `=SORTN` also limits the number of results that are returned dependent on its second argument, which is why changing it adjusts how many results are returned.

If you want information on how to "freeze" the value of `=RANDARRAY` so it doesn't recalculate each time you change something, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201364) by player0.

Functions used:

- [=MAKEARRAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202?hl=en)
- [=LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)
- [=ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)
- [=FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)
- [=SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en)
- [=RANDARRAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904?hl=en)