# Stop formula after a value reached

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to achieve the following...

- A cell with formula, shall stop calculating, once the value previously calculated is reached to certain value. (Shall never calculate it)
- Cell A1: Current Price ( Always changing after 5 minutes )
- Cell B1: Target Price ( Fixed Entry, Not Changing )
- Cell C1: Target Achieved Formula i.e. (A1>B1)
- **The cell C1 shall stop calculating once the formula evaluates to TRUE.**

Any guidance will be appreciated. ( Need to avoid creating circular references )

Comment: Post sample data.

Comment: can cell A1 drop? see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201364/5632629

Comment: Just read #66201364. Totally blown away by depth and quality of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment of `player0` helped to find the solution.
`see: stackoverflow.com/q/66201364/5632629 – player0`

Sample Data below as an example with `CompanyA` in focus.

- CURPRICE can go up and down on interval
- TARGETPRICE is fixed once
- ACHIEVED is TRUE/FALSE based on current price to target
- ACHIEVEDONCE is expected to be TRUE ONCE and remain so forever

```
---- STAGE INITIAL ------------------------------------------
Col - A        B         C            D         E
Row 0 SYMBOL   CURPRICE  TARGETPRICE  ACHIEVED  ACHIEVEDONCE
>Row 1 CompanyA   150      185         FALSE     FALSE 
Row 2 CompanyB   1100     1450         FALSE     FALSE 
Row 3 CompanyC     85       80         TRUE      TRUE 
-------------------------------------------------------------

---- STAGE TARGET ACHIEVED ----------------------------------
Col - A        B         C            D         E
Row 0 SYMBOL   CURPRICE  TARGETPRICE  ACHIEVED  ACHIEVEDONCE
>Row 1 CompanyA   190      185         *TRUE*    *TRUE* 
Row 2 CompanyB   1100     1450         FALSE     FALSE 
Row 3 CompanyC     85       80         TRUE      TRUE 
-------------------------------------------------------------
*FormulaOutputValueChanged*

---- STAGE TARGET ACHIEVED BUT PRICE DOWN -------------------
Col - A        B         C            D         E
Row 0 SYMBOL   CURPRICE  TARGETPRICE  ACHIEVED  ACHIEVEDONCE
>Row 1 CompanyA   160      185         *FALSE*   TRUE 
Row 2 CompanyB   1100     1450         FALSE     FALSE 
Row 3 CompanyC     85       80         TRUE      TRUE 
-------------------------------------------------------------
*FormulaOutputValueChanged*
```

ACHIEVED Column D has a formula as `=ArrayFormula(B2:B>C2:C)`

ACHIEVEDONCE Column E given formula using the LAMBDA function and Sheets setting of calculation allowing "Iterative calculation" with value 5 iteration.

`=ArrayFormula(lambda(cur, achieved, IF(cur=TRUE,cur,achieved))(E2:E,D2:D)`

Hope this helps